# Magento image resizing - own method

Tags: magento-1.9, image, image-resizing

Is Magento preparing images while the page is loaded by the device or use cached images regardless the device size?

If it creates and caching images - same for each device - I would like to change it and load images resized to the exact size required by the device so it could increase page loading speed `(I hope)`.

If it is a good idea `what/which` function should I rewrite?

What do you think guys ?

I already started a imgproxy server which is resizing/cropping images, image url, width, height then send it to the server and display returned "optimized" image. Not sure where to add/change the code, any suggestions ?

Partially problem solved, still I would like to do it better.